# Mount /usr on different partition

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, partition

I want to mount /usr directory on different partition and keep the same owner on all files and subdirectories in /usr directory.

I want to mention that this issue is for linux ec2 machine where I can't enter to the single-user runlevel.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is almost certainly possible.

---

- Mount the new partition somewhere in your filesystem.

  - `mount /path/to/device /mnt`
- Copy the contents of your current /usr to the new partition.

  - `rsync -a /usr /mnt`
- Unmount the new partition.

  - `umount /mnt`
- Update your /etc/fstab to reflect the changes.

  - `/path/to/device /usr defaults 0 0`
- Mount the new partition.

  - `mount /usr`

Comment: I've already done this but all the files and directories are owned by the root user and some services cannot access certain files in /usr

Comment: On a CentOS system I have to hand there are only a handful of directories and files in /usr that aren't owned by uid/gid 0 and the rsync command copies the ownership/permissions on these correctly.

Comment: Be careful with this because that don't seem to be working e.g on Ubuntu (see link). Also it's probably a good idea to use `-H` option to copy hard links as there are some in `/usr` directory and `rsync -a` doesn't include hard links. See problems on Ubuntu here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167612/ubuntu-doesnt-boot-after-moving-usr-from-hdd-to-ssd-nvme